# ASMX web services objects issue

Tags: web-services, asmx

I'm currently working on some web services network (ASP.NET 3.5 web services).
My business layer is similar for all services - it means I have same structs with same fields in each service.

But when I pass these structs between the services, every time I need to make a transformation from global type to local type, for example:

If I have a method that returns instance of struct.

```
[WebMethod]
public MyObject MyMethod () {
return new MyObject();
}
```

When I call it from client service I write something like this:

```
OuterService proxy = new OuterService();
global::MyObject obj = proxy.MyMethod();
```

Where OuterService is an instance of class generated by wsdl.exe.
And then, to pass it to next service I need to tranform it from global type to local type field by field and property by property.

So, my question is:

Is there any elegant solution to pass these objects without transformation on each level?

I thought about creating universal business layer for all web services (which for instance may be declared as web-service too), but to do it I need to change too many things and I think there must be easier solution for this, provided by framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use "Add Service Reference". By default, it shares types that are in assemblies referenced by your project. Just add a reference to the assembly containing the types, use "Add Service Reference" or "Update Service Reference", and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanx for the response. I can't do that because doing this way (as I know) I will not be able change service IP adress dynamically. I have something like 10 services with same WSDL that run on different machines. It's not a good solution to add 10 service references.

Comment: That's not the case. You can change the URL either through configuring it in the `<client>` element of your config file, or when you create the proxy instance. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't by default share types across web services boundaries - but there are some workarounds, like [this article shows](http://www.freddes.se/2009/02/16/multiple-web-service-references-sharing-types/)

Hope this helps